# Handling Time Zone Conversion in PowerShell Script for User Messages

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PowerShell script where I have a file containing start and end times in PST. The goal is to display a user message stating that the system cannot be used between the start and end times. However, I need to consider the user's time zone and display the start and end times in their local time zone.

I have written the following code to achieve this, but **I am facing an issue where users in different time zones are seeing the same start and end times from the file.** Could you please help me identify and resolve the issue. Below code for reference?

```
$format = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"  # Specify the expected format here

$startTimePST = [System.DateTime]::MinValue
$startvalue ="7/10/2023 8:30:45 AM"  //given in file


[System.DateTime]::TryParseExact($startvalue, $format, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref]$startTimePST)


$endTimePST = [System.DateTime]::MinValue
$stopvalue ="7/10/2023 4:08:45 PM"  //given in file

[System.DateTime]::TryParseExact($stopvalue, $format, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref]$endTimePST)



# Get the user's local time zone
$userTimeZone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local

# Convert current system time to PST
$currentSystemTimePST = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc([DateTime]::UtcNow, [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"))

# Convert start and end times to the user's time zone
$startTimeLocal = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime($startTimePST, [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById($userTimeZone.Id))
$endTimeLocal = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime($endTimePST, [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById($userTimeZone.Id))

# Compare the current system time with the start and end times
if ($currentSystemTimePST -ge $startTimePST -and $currentSystemTimePST -le $endTimePST) {
    $message = "The system cannot be used between $startTimeLocal and $endTimeLocal."
    Write-Host $message
}
```

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to ensure that the start and end times are displayed correctly according to the user's time zone. Thank you!"

Answer (score 1):

For cross-timezone timestamp handling, it's best to work with [`[datetimeoffset]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset) instances rather than with [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime).

```bash
# Get the target time zone.
$tz = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById('Pacific Standard Time')

# Convert the timestamp strings to *unspecified* [datetime] instances, 
# then interpret them as being in the target time zone in order to construct 
# [datetimeoffset] instances.
$start, $stop = 
  foreach ($dt in [datetime[]] ('7/10/2023 8:30:45 AM', '7/10/2023 4:08:45 PM')) {
    [datetimeoffset]::new(
      $dt,
      $tz.GetUtcOffset($dt)
    )
  }

# Get the current timestamp as a [datetimeoffset] instance
$now = [datetimeoffset]::now

# Output all timestamps in local time, as [datetime] instances
[pscustomobject] @{
  Start = $start.LocalDateTime
  Stop = $stop.LocalDateTime
  Now = $now.LocalDateTime
}
```